# xml parsing using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a combobox and when users select them xml is parsed.

if i choose item1, i need to select this "C:\folder1" as a path.
item 2: "C:\folder2"
item 3: "C:\folder3"

my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<main>
    <target>C:\folder1</target>
    <target>C:\folder2</target>
    <target>C:\folder3</target>
</main>
```

I am using Xdocument to do the parsing:

```
        private void pathselection()
    {
        XDocument pathdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\GUI\path.xml");
        var abc = from target in pathdoc.Descendants("target")
                  ...
                  ...

    }
```

now i am stuck over here. should i include if statements inside pathselection()? and how do i parse the path?

EDIT1:

Btw, i would like to store these path as strings

```
string selectedpath1 = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the selectable items in the `ComboBox` match the items in the XML, you can get the `target` elements by index:

```
private void pathselection()
{
    XDocument pathdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\GUI\path.xml");
    var abc = pathdoc.Descendants("target")
                  .Where((e, i) => i == MyComboBox.SelectedIndex)
                  .Single();        
}
```

You might want to handle things like when the indexes don't match and you might want to use `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault` to deal with that.

Comment: hi what do u mean by when selected items in combobox matches the items in xml? means i have to add the selected item as a tag instead of `target`? this means that my xml: `<main><one>C:\folder1</one><two>C:\folder2</two><three>C:\folder3</three></main>`

Comment: I mean that unless you bind the `ComboBox` using the xml data, you have to make sure that you have the same number of items so that you can match the selection to the data. You need three items in the `ComboBox`. When you choose the first one, it will have index 0 which will choose your first `<target>` element using the code in my sample. 
However, I do think you might be better off binding the `ComboBox` using the xml data and perhaps you can add some attributes to the data if you'd like something different as the visible text. 
On the other hand, I might have misunderstood your question?